# Getting Error while Overriding GenerateProductionOrders Method of MRPDisplay graph in acumatica

Tags: acumatica, acumatica-kb

Getting Error while Overriding GenerateProductionOrders Method of MRPDisplay graph in acumatica.
I have Extend MRPdisplay graph.

```
  protected delegate void GenerateProductionOrdersDelegate(List<AMOrderCrossRef> list);
 [PXOverride]
protected virtual void GenerateProductionOrders(List<AMOrderCrossRef> list, GenerateProductionOrdersDelegate baseMethod) {
  if(list == null || list.Count == 0) {
    return;
  }

  if(list.Count == 1) {
    PXLongOperation.StartOperation(this, () => {
      CreateProductionOrders(PXGraph.CreateInstance<ProdMaint>(), list);
    });
    return;
  }
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

please try this one:

```
  public class MRPDisplay_Extension : PXGraphExtension<MRPDisplay>
  {
    [PXOverride]
    public void GenerateProductionOrders(List<AMOrderCrossRef> list, Action<List<AMOrderCrossRef>> baseMethod)
    {
      baseMethod(list);
    }
  }
```

You can always go to the Code editor and check if you can override or not the method:

[image]